# Run Sqoop with python 3 using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqoop

I am trying to run Sqoop command with python

```
subprocess.call(["sqoop","import","--connect", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/ARSMTREP","--username", "username" ,"--password", "password","--table","ARADMIN."+line,"--as-textfile","--target-dir","/data/"+line])
```

able to execute this code but when I am trying to execute with "--fields-terminated-by"+" "+"'~'" it's giving tool import error

```
process=subprocess.call(["sqoop","import","--connect", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/ARSMTREP","--username", "hadoop_user" ,"--password", "password","--table","ARADMIN."+line,"--fields-terminated-by"+" "+"'~'","--as-textfile","--target-dir","/data/"+line])
```

> Error parsing arguments for import

Comment: hello Indrajit, I just started working with sqoop. Can you tell me how you imported data from mysql to hdfs using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
process=subprocess.call(["sqoop","import","--connect", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/ARSMTREP","--username", "hadoop_user" ,"--password", "password","--table","ARADMIN."+line,"--fields-terminated-by","~","--as-textfile","--target-dir","/data/"+line])
```

This code call the sqoop command and executes them from linux terminal . Subprocess call [Python subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) you can also use `os.system()` to execute the Sqoop query from python . But its preferable the call Subprocess .
There is no white space in arguments inside the `subprocess.call()` or else it will provide the error.

In above code all the argument are Sqoop command only the `line`is variable which takesthe table name from list.

Comment: Please try to add some text to explain what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`process=subprocess.call(["sqoop","import","--connect", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/ARSMTREP","--username", "hadoop_user" ,"--password", "password","--table","ARADMIN."+line,"--fields-terminated-by","'~'","--as-textfile","--target-dir","/data/"+line])`

Comment: This code executes the code properly but changes the file separator

Comment: @IndrajitSwain Ok.actually I am not from Python background. I was thinking of using "'~'" or "~".